# Error when installing XLConnect in RStudio on OSX 10.13.2

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

I am using RStudio version 1.1.414 on OSX 10.13.2
Please assist me in resolving the error that appears.
The error message that appears when I attempt to load XLConnect is a below:

```
library("XLConnect", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library")

Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded

library("XLConnectJars", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library")

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance